# Netbeans7.1.1 - tomcat 6.0.35 Deployment Error - Deployment error: Access to Tomcat server has not been authorized

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, netbeans-7

I created a Java Web project in Netbeans and index.jsp file was created by default which has "Hello World". I tried to run it but getting the below error -

`Deployment error: Access to Tomcat server has not been authorized. Set the correct username and password with the "manager" role in the Tomcat customizer in the Server Manager.See the server log for details.`

After reading some blogs, I modified tomcat-users.xml file and currently it appears like -

```
<tomcat-users>
  <!--
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
-->
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <role rolename="admin"/>
  <role rolename="standard"/>
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager,standard"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Also, checked for username and password under `Tools->Servers->Connection` in netbeans and its correct i.e. admin/admin.

But still getting the same deployment error.

It displays error in `build-impl.xml` in line -

```
 <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="true" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
```

Did clean and build but no luck.

Apache Tomcat log shows -

```
Nov 29, 2012 6:10:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve custom
SEVERE: Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=401, location=/401.jsp]
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:604)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:438)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:342)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\work\Catalina\localhost\manager\org\apache\jsp\_401_jsp.java (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:104)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.setupContextWriter(Compiler.java:298)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:230)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    ... 20 more

Nov 29, 2012 6:10:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve custom
SEVERE: Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=401, location=/401.jsp]
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:604)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:438)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:342)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\work\Catalina\localhost\manager\org\apache\jsp\_401_jsp.java (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:104)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.setupContextWriter(Compiler.java:298)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:230)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    ... 20 more

Nov 29, 2012 6:10:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve custom
SEVERE: Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=401, location=/401.jsp]
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class for JSP
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:161)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:340)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:438)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:342)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class for JSP
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:630)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:149)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp._401_jsp
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:134)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:628)
    ... 21 more
```

Could anybody plz suggest? Thanks.

Comment: Did you restart the tomcat after you've changed the tomcat-users.xml?

Comment: Paulius Matulionis - Yes, I did restart it.

Comment: I don't know much about Netbeans, but I've heard that sometimes it's doing crap to you applications. What I would suggest is to build your project with the clean and build, start tomcat from command line and try to deploy your application manually from http://localhost:8080/manager/html, tomcat's manager page and check server logs if the issue occurs.

Comment: I think I got some hint from the logs above but not sure how to resolve it. `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\work\Catalina\localhost\manager\org\apache\jsp\_401_jsp.java (The system cannot find the path specified)` . Actually under `CATALINA_HOME\work..` class files get created but as I have choosen a different location for my project other than `CATALINA_HOME\webapps`, _jsp.class files are not getting created. That is causing this problem as seems to me. Not sure how to resolve it. Any pointers you gurus out there?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. With netbeans 7, one needs tomcat 7 as well. tomcat 6 didn't work.