# Netbeans7.4 build-impl.xml:1045 : Access to tomcat server has not been authorized

Tags: tomcat7, netbeans-7

I've created a project in Netbeans 7.4 and Apache 7.0.41.0 All of a sudden when I'm trying to run the project it is giving the error.

> Deployment error: Access to Tomcat server has not been authorized. Set the correct username and password with the "manager-script" role in the Tomcat customizer in the Server Manager.See the server log for details.

can some one say how can I solve this error?

Comment: This may be a silly question, but did you try doing *exactly what the text in the error message tells you to do to fix it*? Did you search here for previous posts with this error message, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10241539) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13625930)? Also, [this one about the manager script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20621884) might help.

Comment: I've tried all the above solutions still it is giving that error.. and 1) when I tried to see the log files it is giving FileNotFoundException for catelina.log,localhost.log,manager.log,hostmanager.log,local_host_manager_log.txt. 2) After that I've created other project even then it is giving  same problem for me.  3) After that I've removed my tomcat server from netbeans server and I've added once again. Still I'm getting same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a option that you use XAMPP(link: https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)? XAMPP comes with a tomcat server, which you can easily turn it on or off.

Comment: After wasting 1hour search what to do your answer helped me.